# Delete an array of queue objects

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, queue, delete-operator

I am working on an object that contains an array of `queues` with an array length that isn't decided until the constructor is called. Basically it looks something like the following

```
#include <queue>

class myClass{
public:
  //public functions
private:
  //private functions and variables

  queue<int>* myQueue;
};
```

it is initialized like so:

```
myClass::myClass(int numOfQueues){
  myQueue = new queue<int>[numOfQueues];
}
```

This all works beautifully, it seems.  it functions exactly like I was hoping it would, but now every time I exit the program I get a segmentation fault.  The class has some other arrays in it that are initialized in the same way, but those are of types `bool` and `int` instead of queue.  My destructor looks like:

```
myClass::~myClass(){
  delete boolArray;
  delete intArray;
  delete myQueue;
}
```

Now I assume this destructor is working for the `boolArray` and `intArray` pointers, because I didn't start to get a segfault until I added `myQueue`.  Does anyone have any idea what the proper way is to write the destructor?  Is it possible that this is all I have to do and the destructor just isn't being called at the proper time?

Comment: If you are not deleting `myQueue` anywhere before the `myClass` destructor, there is no reason that deleting it will cause a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you allocated using `new[]` you should do `delete[] myQueue;` in destructor. Otherwise it would invoke undefined behavior. BTW, you can use `std::vector<std::queue<int> >` if you don't want to get this type of memory management issues.

Comment: Oh, wow, that was an unbelievably obvious mistake for me to make.  That fixed the problem.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Why're you not using `std::vector` instead of arrays?

You need to `delete[]` arrays, not `delete` - you allocated with `new[]`

Comment: I'm not using vector because I have never used them before and had no idea they would be a better solution to my problem.  I will definitely look into vectors for the future, though.  Thanks.  Edit:  Actually I just read a summary of the uses of vectors, and I think vectors would be unnecessary here.  After initializing the array it doesn't ever change size.  The size just isn't hard-coded, it is decided based on user input.

Comment: @Alex: take a look at the `vector::reserve` method, it might be useful for your requirements. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/reserve/

Comment: @Alex: when considering using a vector (like most here suggest), take also in account that with a vector member, you don't need a destructor or a copy constructor or an operator=() which is needed for dynamic arrays as member (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).

Answer (score 1):

Using `delete` with `new[]` won't just cause memory leak but also invokes Undefined behaviour.

The correct form of `delete` to be used with `new[]` is `delete[]`.

However in idiomatic C++ it is always recommended to use `std::vector` instead of using C style arrays. You need not explicitly manage memory yourself when you use STL containers.

Comment: That's good to know.  I already have the code working as it is so I think I will leave it alone for the moment, but I will definitely keep that in mind next time I need to do something similar.

Comment: Real men don't use vectors! New and delete is like mens tools, you buy a New tool and delete a used one. Vectors in other hand are nice but they are more like ladies handbags, you fill them up with all sorts of crap to soon throw the bag away to buy a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Naveen has already solved the problem. I'd like to add a good programming practice.

The following use case below will also create deletion problems.

```
void foo()
{
    myClass a;
    myClass b(a);
}
```

when we declare **a**, a new instance of myQueue will be created. However when declaring **b**, copy constructor will be called instead of *myClass::myClass(int numQueues)* constructor. Thus ***a***.myQueue == **b**.myQueue.

When exiting function *foo*, **a**'s destructor will delete **myQueue** then **b**'s destructor will try to **delete an unreferenced pointer** which would lead to a fatal error.

A good programming practice is to either implement *copy constructor* and *= operator* accordingly or to declare *copy constructor* and *= operator* **private** to avoid such problems.

```
private:
    myClass(const myClass&);
    const myClass& operator=(const myClass&);
```

See also **boost::NonCopyable**