# C++ Global Array of Queues with variable size

Tags: c++, arrays, compiler-errors, queue

I am working on a project that requires a class QueueArray that is an Array of Queues. It's been a while since I worked with c++ Arrays so I'm having some trouble debugging why my code is throwing errors.

I read [Delete an array of queue objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388373/c-delete-an-array-of-queue-objects) for some inspiration (along with a couple hours on Google), but I am still having errors with the following code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <deque>
    #include <queue>
    using namespace std;

    class QueueArray
    {

        queue<int> theArray[];

        QueueArray::QueueArray(int size)
        {
            queue<int> theArray[] = new queue<int>[size];
            //theArray[] = new queue<int>[size]; //this may be closer, but also giving errors

        }
    };
```

the errors are:

warning C4200: nonstandard extension used : zero-sized array in struct/union
1>          Cannot generate copy-ctor or copy-assignment operator when UDT contains a zero-sized array

and

error C2075: 'theArray' : array initialization needs curly braces

I've read up about the 2nd error, but I can seem to figure out what I need to do to fix it.

I need it to be a variable sized array, with the variable passed to the class, which is why I can not initialize the size of the array up top, and It must be of global scope so I can use it in other functions within the class (the classes can't be passed the array through a parameter).

Later on, the queues will be of a user defined type, but we're letting them be queues of ints right now, not sure if that makes a difference. I keep seeing people suggesting the use of vectors in these cases but I don't have a choice on this one.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using variable sized arrays is not possible in C++. to make your code working, use a pointer, i.e.

```
class QueueArray
{
    queue<int> * const theArray;

    QueueArray::QueueArray(int size)
    : theArray (new queue<int>[size])
    { /* ... */ }
    ~QueueArray()
    { delete[] theArray; }
};
```

However, in C++ you should really avoid this and use a `std::vector` instead, i.e.

```
typedef vector<queue<int>> QueueArray;
```

Comment: Thank you, I've never that type of syntax before, but it worked!

a/b vectors: I know vectors would be a lot easier, but it was not my choice.

Answer (score 3):

```
queue<int>* theArray;
```

not

```
queue<int> theArray[];
```

Answer (score 3):

When allocating an array on the heap you get back a pointer to the start of the array, rather than an array. Thus, you want to declare your array as

```
queue<int>* theArray;
```

The use of empty brackets is allowed in some contexts but has specific meaning. It can be used when initializing a statically size array:

```
queue<int> theArray[] = { queue<int>(), queue<int>() /*...*/ };
```

creates an array of a size matching the list of initializers and it still can be empty. You can also use empty brackets in the argument list of a function in which case the use is equivalent to using pointer notation, e.g.:

```
int main(int ac, char* av[])
```

is identical to

```
int main(int ac, char** av)
```

Comment: Okay, I'd always used the empty bracket notation in the past, but I'd also never tried to create a G array with it's size undetermined like this. Thank you for your response.